# PrimeNG 9: display values selected in p-multiselect in reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, primeng-dropdowns

I am trying to use the PrimeNG Multi-Select in a reactive form using [their documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect), which is pretty lacking relating to reactive forms.

What I am trying to do is display the selected items below the form control as in their example, except their example uses `ngModel` not a reactive form control.

I created the rest of my code as in their example, created a variable

```
  divisionList: SelectItem[];
```

and populated it in the constructor as shown in their example.

Then I create the form control defined in a formBuilder form:

```
  fg = this.fb.group({
    ...
    divisions: ['']
  });
```

and the html is

```
<p-multiSelect
          [options]="divisionList"
          formControlName="divisions"
          defaultLabel="Select"
        ></p-multiSelect>
```

Their simple ngModel-based approach is `<p>Selected Cars: {{selectedCars1}}</p>`

But I'm not using ngModel.  So, how do I display the selected items in the template?

#### Update:

I'm still hoping there's a simpler way but so far I managed to add a change handler:

```
       <p-multiSelect
          [options]="divisionList"
          formControlName="divisions"
          dropdownIcon="pi pi-caret-down"
          defaultLabel="Select"
          (onChange)="selectDivision($event)"
        ></p-multiSelect>
```

and the function:

```
selectDivision(e) {
  this.selectedDivisions = e.value.map((item) => item.name);
  if (this.selectedDivisions.length > 3) {
    this.selectedItemDisplay = `Selected items: ${this.selectedDivisions.join(', ')}`;
  } else {
    this.selectedItemDisplay = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.form.controls['divisions'].value`? So, `<p>Selected Cars: {{this.fg.controls['divisions'].value}}</p>`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I get `Selected items: [object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: How about `this.fg.controls['divisions'].value.map(i => i.value).join(', ')`?

Comment: nope, error "bindings cannot contain assignments"

Comment: I had that problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332904/primeng-p-multiselect-with-reactive-form-setting-value-dynamically